# confused about creating new columns efficiently in R using mutate and rollmean function applied on only numeric columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the below (sample of a large) dataset. Please note there might be NAs in the beginning of any of the series, though I have not shown in the below sample data.

```
df <- data.frame(Date = rev(seq(as.Date("2021-01-01"),as.Date("2021-01-20"),"day")),
              Var1 = sample(10:100, 20, replace = TRUE), 
              Var2 = sample(10:100, 20, replace = TRUE), 
              Var3 = sample(10:100, 20, replace = TRUE), 
              Var4 = sample(10:100, 20, replace = TRUE),
              Var5 = letters[1:20],
              Var6 = letters[7:26]
              )
```

I wanted to compute rolling means for each series i.e. for Var1: 3 day rolling means, 4 day rolling means and 7 day rolling means.

I can do it using the following:

```
df <- tibble(df) %>%
        mutate(Var1_3DMA = rollmean(Var1, k = 3, fill = NA)) %>%  
        mutate(Var1_4DMA = rollmean(Var1, k = 4, fill = NA)) %>% 
        mutate(Var1_7DMA = rollmean(Var1, k = 7, fill = NA))
```

I want to do it for all the numeric variables only (i.e. leave all the date and character variables and then compute rolling means).

Also I want to create (mutate) new variables using `original name` followed by an underscore `_` i.e. Var1_3DMA , Var1_4DMA, Var1_7DMA, Var2_3DMA , Var2_4DMA, Var2_7DMA and so forth.

Is there an efficient way of doing it in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(dplyr); library(zoo)

df %>%
  mutate(across(Var1:Var4,
                list(`3DMA` = ~ rollmean(.x, k=3, fill = NA),
                     `4DMA` = ~ rollmean(.x, k=4, fill = NA),
                     `7DMA` = ~ rollmean(.x, k=7, fill = NA))))

         Date Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6 Var1_3DMA Var1_4DMA Var1_7DMA Var2_3DMA Var2_4DMA Var2_7DMA Var3_3DMA Var3_4DMA Var3_7DMA Var4_3DMA Var4_4DMA Var4_7DMA
1  2021-01-20   77   76   53   57    a    g        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
2  2021-01-19   94   76   99   33    b    h  80.00000     72.50        NA  67.33333     73.00        NA  79.00000     70.25        NA  35.00000     36.00        NA
3  2021-01-18   69   50   85   15    c    i  71.00000     62.50        NA  72.00000     60.75        NA  76.00000     80.00        NA  29.00000     29.75        NA
4  2021-01-17   50   90   44   39    d    j  52.00000     45.25  63.71429  55.66667     64.00  71.85714  73.66667     69.75  74.42857  28.66667     39.75  40.85714
5  2021-01-16   37   27   92   32    e    k  37.33333     51.50  64.28571  68.66667     75.25  65.71429  64.66667     71.00  70.14286  48.00000     45.25  40.14286
6  2021-01-15   25   89   58   73    f    l  52.00000     59.25  65.14286  70.33333     61.00  68.57143  80.00000     65.75  67.71429  47.33333     48.50  43.57143
7  2021-01-14   94   95   90   37    g    m  66.66667     75.00  69.28571  72.33333     78.25  67.14286  57.00000     63.25  66.00000  54.00000     54.75  44.57143
8  2021-01-13   81   33   23   52    h    n  91.66667     93.25  70.85714  74.66667     66.00  58.85714  65.00000     67.00  73.42857  48.66667     42.00  52.28571
9  2021-01-12  100   96   82   57    i    o  93.00000     85.00  79.28571  56.33333     50.25  57.42857  59.33333     68.50  62.14286  43.66667     56.00  53.57143
10 2021-01-11   98   40   73   22    j    p  86.33333     88.75  80.00000  56.00000     46.25  53.71429  83.66667     66.00  57.14286  57.33333     53.25  51.71429
11 2021-01-10   61   32   96   93    k    q  85.00000     71.25  73.14286  29.66667     38.00  51.85714  60.66667     51.25  47.00000  52.00000     54.00  57.71429
12 2021-01-09   96   17   13   41    l    r  62.33333     58.25  70.57143  37.33333     48.50  52.71429  44.00000     37.75  55.85714  64.66667     68.25  56.42857
13 2021-01-08   30   63   23   60    m    s  57.33333     58.75  59.28571  54.00000     50.25  43.00000  18.33333     35.00  46.00000  60.00000     55.75  57.71429
14 2021-01-07   46   82   19   79    n    t  46.33333     40.00  55.00000  61.33333     53.00  42.57143  42.33333     35.00  43.28571  60.66667     62.00  60.42857
15 2021-01-06   63   39   85   43    o    u  43.33333     49.50  60.42857  49.66667     46.50  50.28571  39.00000     42.75  36.00000  62.66667     57.25  50.57143
16 2021-01-05   21   28   13   66    p    v  50.66667     62.75  49.28571  34.66667     47.50  55.28571  50.66667     49.25  40.57143  50.00000     43.50  58.71429
17 2021-01-04   68   37   54   41    q    w  62.66667     51.50  48.00000  50.33333     50.75  58.28571  37.33333     39.25  44.28571  43.66667     57.25  59.85714
18 2021-01-03   99   86   45   24    r    x  61.66667     51.50        NA  58.33333     64.75        NA  48.00000     48.25        NA  54.33333     57.75        NA
19 2021-01-02   18   52   45   98    s    y  46.00000        NA        NA  74.00000        NA        NA  46.33333        NA        NA  63.33333        NA        NA
20 2021-01-01   21   84   49   68    t    z        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` to pass multiple `k` values in `rollmean`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(zoo)

k <- c(3, 4, 7)

map(k, function(n) df %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), 
              ~rollmean(., n, fill = NA), .names = '{sprintf("%s_%dDMA", .col, n)}'))) %>%
  reduce(inner_join, by = names(df))
```